# Why do Linq lambdas not require a `return` statement, but mine do?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, delegates, lambda

I'm using lambdas quite a bit in a library. One thing that really irks me is I can't seem to get rid of the return statement and I have have quite a bit of boiler-plate type code around them.

This is how it works so far:

```
public delegate IBarelyView HandlerInvoker(IDictionary<string, string> route, IDictionary<string, string> form);
public void MyFunc(string foo, HandlerInvoker invoker) { }
```

This is the code I have worker to use MyFunc:

```
MyFunc("foobar", (x, y) => { return new Xyz();});
```

Now I know this isn't too bad. However, I'd really like to be able to use the Linq type syntax. For instance, it's easy enough to do

```
ObjectList.Where(x=>x.Foo=="bar");
```

As you can see, positives for the Linq syntax is no `return` statement, no parentheses around the "arguments", and no curly braces.

Why can't I have this kind of syntax in my lambdas? If I remove the return statement I get an error about not all code paths returning a value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:    `MyFunc("foobar", (x, y) => new Xyz());`

Comment: I can't remember for the life of me why I was using the curly braces in the first place. I assume that it's their fault for requiring a return statement?>

Comment: The braces wraps a block of statement(s) hence the need for a return. Glad it worked :) I was terrified there considering your amazing rep ;)

Comment: @Earlz: the relevant terminology here is "expression lambdas" and "statement lambdas".

Comment: @LewsTherin well, we all have our dumb moments and rep doesn't equate to experience (though I really should've known that one with how long I've been working with .Net)